# NodeJS synchronously change directory

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

I have the following code in NodeJS:

```
var targetDir = tmpDir + date;

try {
    fs.statSync(targetDir);
}
catch (e) {
    mkdirp.sync(targetDir, {mode: 755});
}

process.chdir(targetDir);

doStuffThatDependsOnBeingInTargetDir();
```

My understanding is that in NodeJS, functions such process.chdir are asynchronously executed.  So if I need execute some code afterwards, how do I guarantee that I'm in the directory before I execute my subsequent function?

If process.chdir took a callback then I would do it in the callback.  But it doesn't.  This asynchronous paradigm is definitely confusing for a newcomer so I figured I would ask.  This isn't the most practical consideration since the code seems to work anyways.  But I feel like I'm constantly running into this and don't know how to handle these situations.

Comment: Where does it state that it's an asynchronous function? You should definately be okay with your code.

Comment: @DanielB - Where does it state that it's a synchronous function?  It's confusing as shit.  Aren't all functions in Node async supposed to be async unless it specifically says that they are synchronous?  Just looking for more precise understanding as to why the code works and why it will always work.

Comment: I can't find any source for that, but I know that `process.chdir()` is a synchronous function. It is a good question though as some functions are async and some sync, and it doesn't state anywhere which one is which.

Answer (score 0):

`process.chdir()` [function](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory) is a synchronous function. As you said yourself, it does not have a callback function to tell if it succeeded or not. It does however throw an exception if something goes wrong so you would want to invoke it inside a `try catch` block.

You can check if the process successfully changed directory by `process.cwd()` [function](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd).